# Home Page started before data is loaded IONIC 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

The problem I have is really strange. In Ionic 2 in app.component.ts I have this code. The problem is that first it redirects me to Home Page and after that it loads data from the json. So as result at Home Page I get undefined.

The code in app.component.ts :

```
export class MyApp {

 public rootPage : any;

 constructor(public platform: Platform, data : Data) {

 this.platformready();
  data.loadData();

  this.rootPage = HomePage;

 }

 private platformready() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {

   Splashscreen.hide();

 });

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `loadData` return promise:

```
this.platformready();
  data.loadData().then(res => {
    // do something with data
    this.rootPage = HomePage;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // alert error
  });
}
```

if return Observable

```
this.platformready();
  data.loadData().subscribe(res => {
    // do something with data
    this.rootPage = HomePage;
  },err => {
    // alert error
  });
}
```

Comment: @Tipe Phan , but I want to get the data in Home Page. With your solution I will have the data in app.component, not in a provider, so I can't pass it to Home Page.

Comment: oh, you could load data in HomePage, not in `root`, or you could create shared service, then Homepage will receive data from this service, `root` will emit data when this `load done`

Comment: do you have some example code with solution of this problem? Please send if do.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Data` a provider?

If it is just call it in your HomePage inside a `ionViewWillLoad(){}`, like this:

```
constructor(data : Data) {}

ionViewWillLoad(){
  data.loadData();
}
```

And like this you can save it anywhere, in a variable, database, etc.

If it's a data that changes later in the app, you can use `ionViewWillEnter(){}` instead.

Hope it helps :)